# How to plot a function on a limited domain?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Suppose you have the function h defined on the set {1,2,3} with h(x)=x^2-3 and you want to graph it using tikz. How can you do it? Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `samples at`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={h(\x)=\x*\x-3;}]
 \draw[-stealth] (0,0) -- (4,0) node[below left]{$x$};
 \draw[-stealth] (0,-3) -- (0,6) node[below left]{$h(x)$};
 \draw[only marks,mark=*] plot[samples at={1,2,3}] (\x,{h(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with `pgfplots`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={h(\x)=\x*\x-3;}]
 \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,xmin=0,enlargelimits=0.1,
    ylabel={$h(x)$},xlabel={$x$},xtick={1,2,3},ytick={-4,-3,...,6}]
  \addplot[only marks,mark=*,samples at={1,2,3}] {h(\x)};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it also possible to mark the x-axis and y-axis with 1,2,3,4,...?